# Simple & easy way to jail users

Tags: ssh, users, chroot

I need a simple and easy way to jail users in their home directories in Oneiric. Do you have a simple configuration for jailing users, with full help, or some good web links?

I would be offering an online free public server with 10 to 20 GB free space. I don't know how many users. I want to give them SSH and SFTP so that they can connect through FileZilla.

Comment: 2nd update if users are not locked in home directories

Comment: then I believe you 1-as mentioned by @Marco you want to try ChrootDirectory for SSH 2- you may want to go beyond the standard ways of doing things as you need to scale this to handle "a lot" of storage, ... 3- Is SSH your best choice? do people need SSH on your service? 4- Good luck

Comment: i have other plan as well .... for normal users we would be offering only SFTP with MY SECURE SHELL , that's very easy 2 handle

Comment: How can I remove this jail e.g.(home/jail)?<br>
And when I add some jail section e.g. jk_init -v -f /home/jail netutils, how will I remove this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Jailkit is a set of utilities that can limit user accounts to a specific directory tree and to specific commands. Setting up a jail is much easier using the Jailkit utilities that doing so 'by hand'. A jail is a directory tree that you create within your file system; the user cannot see any directories or files that are outside the jail directory. The user is jailed in that directory and it subdirectories.

#### Download & Install:

http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/index.html#download

```
VERSION=2.20 # from November 2018
cd /tmp
wget https://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/jailkit-$VERSION.tar.gz
tar -zxvf jailkit-$VERSION.tar.gz
cd jailkit-$VERSION/
./configure
make
su -
make install
```

#### Setting up the jail

Now it’s time to set up the jail directory. Jailed users will see this directory as the root directory of the server. I chose to use /home/jail:

```
mkdir /home/jail
chown root:root /home/jail
```

[jk_init can be used to quickly create a jail with several files or directories needed for a specific task or profile, (click on it & read full detail ).](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/jailkit.8.html)

```
jk_init -v /home/jail basicshell
jk_init -v /home/jail netutils
jk_init -v /home/jail ssh
jk_init -v /home/jail jk_lsh
```

#### Add a user

Add a new user with a home directory and bash shell, and set the password:

```
useradd -d /home/jailtest -m jailtest -s /bin/bash
passwd jailtest
```

#### Now it’s time to jail this user

use the following command:

```
jk_jailuser -m -j /home/jail jailtest
```

Your `/etc/passwd` should contain something like this now:

```
jailtest:x:1001:1001::/home/jail/./home/jailtest:/usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh
```

#### Enable bash

By using [jk_cp](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/jailkit.8.html) the bash libraries are copied to the jail:

```
jk_cp -v -f /home/jail /bin/bash
```

#### Edit `/home/jail/etc/passwd`

replace this line:

```
jailtest:x:1001:1001::test:/usr/sbin/jk_lsh
```

with this:

```
jailtest:x:1001:1001::/home/jailtest:/bin/bash
```

#### Maintenance

By using `jk_update` updates on the real system can be updated in the jail.

A dry-run will show what’s going on:

```
jk_update -j /home/jail -d
```

[Without the -d argument the real update is performed. More maintenance operations can be found here.](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_chroot_shell.html)

(In case `/home/jail/opt` is missing, create it with `mkdir -p /home/jail/opt/`
And run `jk_update -j /home/jail` again)

#### Give access to other directories

You can mount special folders, that the jail user may acces now. E.g.:

```
mount --bind /media/$USER/Data/ /home/jail/home/jailtest/test/
```

### Help Taken

> http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_chroot_shell.html
>
> http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/index.html#intro ( a very good help )
>
> [This one also](http://www.marthijnvandenheuvel.com/2010/03/10/how-to-create-a-chroot-ssh-user-in-ubuntu/)
>
> This is been checked & verified , Working Properly

Comment: +1 very good. highly recommend reading the links you mentioned above in the "Help Taken" section too

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 13.10.  When you try to finally login you get the welcome message immediately followed by connection closed.

Comment: Matt H: Make sure to follow the last two steps; copying the bash binaries and editing the /home/jail/etc/passwd file.

Comment: This either doesnt work anymore or something has changed since this tutorial was put up. Im getting exactly the same problems as MattH.

Comment: I also had the connection closed issue immediately after the welcome message. I changed the login shell within the chroot passwd file from jk_lsh to bash as read here http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/can%27t-access-to-a-user-jailed-by-jailkit-836690/#post4120537 It is not a solution but a workaround!

Comment: Tnks for your answer.
Unfortunately I wasn't able to configure it correctly so the user could connect via sftp. :(

Sep 23 05:39:31 nsXXXXXX jk_chrootsh[2701]: now entering jail /home/jail for user usersftp (1001) with arguments -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Sep 23 05:39:31 nsXXXXXX sshd[2700]: Received disconnect from 84.91.XXX.XXX: 11: disconnected by user

Comment: It seems that the solution does not work anymore on latest ubuntu version: I have done `sudo su - testuser` but nothing happens. What should I do? And `sudo -su testuser` opens at under jail user directory but I can still see others' directory. @MariusMatutiae

Comment: I edited the anwser:  enhance formatting, updated Version to 2.20 and create a variable for it; added `su -` at the right position and renamed testuser to jailtest, to avoid attacks and collitions with other testusers – this works fine on my Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: But it doesn't seem to work on Debian (tested on wheezy and stretch). Here ist the -vvv ssh log: https://pastebin.com/Mwbsz4Wq

Answer (score 7):

You can not confine them to /home as they need access to the system binaries and bash and configuration files in /etc

IMO the easiest method of securing users is to use apparmor.

You make a hard link

```
ln /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/jailbash
```

You add jailbash to /etc/shells

You then assign jailbash to the users shell, and then write an apparmor profile for jailbash allowing minimal access.

```
sudo chsh -s /usr/local/bin/jailbash user_to_confine
```

You will have to write an apparmor profile yourself, but I have a profile you could potentially start with

http://bodhizazen.com/aa-profiles/bodhizazen/ubuntu-10.04/usr.local.bin.jailbash

Comment: `You can not confine them to /home as they need access to the system binaries and bash and configuration files in /etc` There is nothing stopping you from linking/copying files you feel they need.

Comment: Yes you "can" do as  user606723 suggests, but it is not so easy, and IMO of all the potential solutions the least practical or easy. Might as well build a chroot or use lxc. You copy a binary, then the libs. Often you will manually need to identify libs with ldd. This method takes a ton of work to set up. And then you have to keep the jail up to date, you will have to manually update (copy) the binaries / libs. Links might work better in terms of updates, but you still need to set them all up. Somehow I do not think this is what the OP had in mind. How then to keep them confined ?

Comment: I think the whole point of the question was to point out tools to automate this process... like `jailkit`, a tool the OP mentions.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen . what u think about about this .. debootstrap (oneiric) then make a container using lxc . using jail kit > user to container > . what i did so far is  i have debbootstrap oneiric minimum then used jailkit >working fine

Comment: you can use LXC for this task, beware that isolation is sometimes incomplete with LXC. As long as users do not have root access in the container you should be OK and you may want to subscribe to the LXC mailing list.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen. the thing i was thinking is that ...how users go straight to lxc containers ... is the same config i m using with debootstrap ?

Comment: lxc is somewhat similar to a chroot (debootstrap), but it is a bit more complex. Some people use scripts to set up lxc.

Comment: i did with jailkit , debootstrap ....i did it with lxc containers ...i have tested all things ....i just need a way to lock user's in there home directories

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried all three top-voted answers and your one is the easiest. Actually it is the only one which worked for me.

Comment: @caligula - you are most welcome

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to guess what purpose you might want to accomplish. If it is to deny ssh/sftp while providing jailed access via FTP... easy:

Add to /etc/shells a new shell:

```
sudo -e /etc/shells
```

Add one line:

```
/bin/false
```

Save. For each user you want to deny ssh/sftp, change the user's shell:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/false userx
```

Now userx cannot log in via ssh/sftp.

Install vsftpd:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

Edit the config file:

```
sudo -e /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

And some changes....

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Save. Restart vsftpd:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

Comment: well i m want to give them ssh + sftp (connect through filezilla)

Answer (score 0):

You could check out `rbash` as a shell for your users.

```
man bash
```

Search for `RESTRICTED SHELL` section

Or look on this page http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: Just be very careful with rbash, it is very easy to break out of and sort of considered outdated. See http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/how-to-restrict-access-with-rbash/

Comment: @bodhi.zazen You mean `rbash`?

Comment: yes, sorry I fixed that. There was a blog several years ago where someone broke our of a rbash jail I set up, and I though it was tight, minimal jail. Took them less then 5 minutes. Not had anyone break out of jailbash.

Comment: can u plz tell me how do i configure it ....jailbash

Comment: yes, man bash helps, using bash restrited shell capabilities is more simply