# How to configure Samba

Tags: samba, lan

I wonder if there is someone here who knows how to configure Samba in following situation.

I live in a house where all computers are in a local area network. In Windows I'm able to see all my neighbours' and roommates' computers and I can explore my roommates' shared folder (because I have access to do that). In Windows this is all possible automaticly.

In Ubuntu (12.04) I can see all my neighbours' Mac mahcines and few Windows computers in Nautilus' "Network" section but there is usually about 50 computers in network all the time so most of them are not shown. I can't find for example my roommates' computer.

I haven't changed any Samba configurations yet. What should I do to see all computers in LAN?

Answer (score 1):

**How to find the other system without knowing name or IP of the other system in LAN?**
You can use nmap in the terminal, for example:

```
nmap 192.168.0.*
```

if 192.168.0.0 is your LAN. This will print you all network clients in your LAN (which can be discovered). Sometimes this might help, if other machines don't show up under Network.

Reference:
https://askubuntu.com/a/98694/56338

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `smbtree` utility to find all the machines that announce themselves using the NetBIOS protocol, which is often used in combination with SMB on Windows.