# LAN data transfer

Tags: 12.04, wireless, lan, database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sharing files in LAN through Samba or SSH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96849/sharing-files-in-lan-through-samba-or-ssh)

I would to know how can I transfer data using LAN from an Ubuntu machine to another! I am using a wireless router, obviously, I can see mine in the windows network but I guess I must do something else. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install a file sharing server such as SAMBA. Then you can make a shared folder between your windows and Ubuntu hosts. You can download samba from [here](http://www.samba.org/samba/download/) Or you can do it via **synaptic** or **Ubuntu Software center** or via command line

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Comment: yes, I already have Samba though

Comment: also, I can see my laptop from my desktop PC but I can't see my desktop computer from my laptop... I have samba on both and I have made the exact same thing on my laptop as on my Desktop computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Transfer on LAN](http://code.google.com/p/transfer-on-lan/). It needs Java 6 then it works on Ubuntu, Windows, Mac. It is easy to use because no configuration is required.