# Can anyone recommend a good chroot ssh tutorial/ how to for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ssh, chroot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest & Easy Way To Jail Users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93411/simplest-easy-way-to-jail-users)

I'm looking for a good how-to/tutorial on setting up a chrooted ssh environment on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

I'm NOT interested in chrooted sftp which is easy to implement.

It's jailing users in their home directory when they log in via ssh that I'm primarily interested in.

Grateful for any help,

Thanks