# How to give a specific user access only to a specific folder and its contents?

Tags: permissions, apache2, users, ftp, chown

I used

```
adduser <name>
```

and created a new user, andrew. Now I want to give him read/write access **only** to `/var/www/sitename.com` and its contents.

How am I supposed to do this?

I tried `sudo chown andrew /var/www/sitename.com` but he is still able to see all the folders and files under /var/www and other directories.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent users accessing anything but their own home directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/267019/how-can-i-prevent-users-accessing-anything-but-their-own-home-directory)

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/267019/134479). Though the question is not identical, I think the answer fits quite the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the ownership to a designated user will not change the users default home directory specified in **passwd** file. Anyhow, You may achieve this in different ways. But to make it simpler do this by opening up a terminal;

Firstly make a back-up of your `/etc/passwd` file doing below;

```
sudo cp /etc/passwd /etc/passwd.back
```

Once done, edit the file (either with vi or nano), I prefer nano which is pretty easy;

```
sudo EDITOR=nano vipw /etc/passwd
```

Locate the created user. A line should reflect as below assuming the user is `andrew`;

```
andrew:x:1001:1001:andrew:/home/andrew:/bin/sh
```

Replace `/home/andrew` with `/var/www/sitename.com` & save the file by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then enter to save & then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit. This will direct the user to specified directory. Login as the user and see whether it points to **/var/www/sitename.com by also checking for any permission issues. If permission issue persists, then add the user to the `www-data` group by doing below;

```
sudo adduser andrew www-data
```

**EDIT:** regarding the comment, I just had a quick search and found some more detail. Well, you may edit **vsftpd.conf** file located in `/etc/` directory

```
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

un-comment (remove only the `#` if its there at the beginning) the following line;

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Note: Just to be safe, make a back-up of the configuration file before you make any changes to it.

```
sudo cp /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.back
```

**Source:** [vsftpd.conf on Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/vsftpd.conf.5.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: it works, but I still can access other folders

Comment: that is because the user is also in `www-data` group too..

Comment: @VovaStajilov, I had a quick search added few more in-detail by **editing**. I hope it may help you.