# How to give access permission to specific folder by specific user in ubuntu.[Terminal]

Tags: permissions, users

I am having below directory structure.

```
/DR/Sub/X1/...
       /X2/...
       /X3/...
       .......
```

I want to give acces permissions to user but in below manner,
when ever i create new directory like X1,X2,X3 suppose i create X4
i want to create new user for this new directory which will only and only access `/DR/Sub/X4/...` directory.....i.e. new user for new directory how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: additionally to the answers below (that i would suggest you) it depends on what you REALLY want to do. If you want the directories because of SSH users you can think about jailing them to a specific dir: http://www.googlehemsida.se/c/Ubuntu_-_Jail_user_to_folder - it really depends on your intention. See chroot / jail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following commands will create user *X4* and (by default) group *X4* and directory `X4`, and will limit access to directory `X4` to user *X4* exclusively.

```
sudo adduser X4
sudo mkdir X4
sudo chown X4:X4 X4
sudo chmod 0750 X4
```

Note that nothing will prevent *X4* from rummaging around elsewhere on the file system. There is [no way to prevent that](https://askubuntu.com/a/267283/134479). However, no one except *X4* and *root* will be able to access directory `X4`.

Comment: thanks , and if i want to provide some user name and password to access X4 by user X4 then how can i do that?

Comment: Username is X4 (specified by "adduser X4" and password can be set by using the passwd utility: "passwd X4")

Comment: OK thanks i will try it now and if i done i will let u know.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create user using `sudo adduser username --home dir`, where **dir**  can be any directory.

For example `sudo adduser X4 --home /DR/Sub/X4`.

This will create user X4 and specified directory accessible only by X4.

Comment: hi , i have created 2 users X3 and X4 but when i login using X3 it is accessing X4's directory