# Reset permissions on (K)Ubuntu 18.04: newly created user gets "Cannot execute /bin/bash: Permission denied"

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, su

so I seem to have screwed up some permissions on my Ubuntu desktop system. I wanted to let a newly created user only grant access to one single folder (to run in terminal only one app within that folder).

I stumpled over this [threat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267019/how-can-i-prevent-users-accessing-anything-but-their-own-home-directory/579399#579399) and recklessly did a `setfacl -R -m user:$NEWUSER:--- /` Because I thought that user does not need any programs from the amywhere.  I did not realize `/bin/bash` is at least needed.

Now I tryed to delete that user and recreate, but that did not help. And even with another username it won't let me `su` into that user, because it is not allowed to user `/bin/bash`.

How can I repair those permissions again? I only need to let that user use a terminal and run a script up and down... >_<

I hope to find help here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the opposite:

```
setfacl -R -x user:$NEWUSER /
```