# How to permit access only a single folder and restrict other

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, samba, ftp

need Solution,

I need to give a permission to users to access only a specified folder and restrict access other all folder.

Need to create like FTP.

So I had created 3 users and one group (tensult), all 3 users are assigned to this group and changed the group ownership of the folder called /drive

```
drwxrwx--- 2 root tensult 6 Aug 14 11:19 /drive/
```

If users accessed by SSH or FTP, other folders can also have the access to these 3 users.

Or is there any option to set permission to groups

Please help out to solve this

Comment: permission that you see with `ls -l` are listed in 3 parts : owner/groups/others, and 3 types of right for each part, **R**ead, **W**rite and e**X**ecution; in your case, your group `tensult` have all right on this folder

Comment: @damadam, that I know. I just want to give them access only to the specified folder and need to restrict other all folder access

Comment: just change the right on subdirectories, you don't have to touch this one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent users accessing anything but their own home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267019/how-can-i-prevent-users-accessing-anything-but-their-own-home-directory)

Comment: its not working @zwets