# Making all folders not readable to "others" - but keeping their original status regarding "write" and "execute"

Tags: permissions, ssh, remote-access, umask

**TLDR**: How can I change permissions of all folders in the computer such that, for "others", the folders loose only readability? In other words, they keep their status regarding "write" and "execute", but loose the possibility of "reading" in case they had it in the first place?

**Long version**:
While configuring a server (where users can SSH to) for the first time, my first inclination was to try to find out how one could create new users that are allowed to access only their own `home/username` folder and subfolders.

However, I found some references (for examples [this question/answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267019/how-can-i-prevent-users-accessing-anything-but-their-own-home-directory)) online explaining that that would perhaps not be a good idea because users would of course need to still access some system folders like `usr/bin` or `usr/lib` and to write to folders like `tmp`. Of course, it does make sense. Then, what I have tried to accomplish instead is to have users be able to **use** what is in the system folders but not **see** their content.

More specifically, that would mean  setting all folders in the system to not be readable to "others" while still maintaining their original status to "others" in respect to writability and executability. For example, a folder with permission `754` would become `750`, a folder with `756` would become `752`, a folder with `755` would become `751`, etc, while a folder with `753`, `752`, `751` or `750` would stay the same. So on and so forth.

This way, no one besides the root would be able to see what is inside any folder besides their `home/username` folder and subfolders, but she could still execute and write normally throughout all system folders that originally allowed so.

How could I a do that for all folders? Comments on the possible flaws of this idea are of course welcome too.

Comment: I'm asking my self - why `750` octal permission for the user's home directories is not enough to prevent the users to access each `other` user's home directories?

Comment: @pa4080 because in a harsher case, I wanted to prevent users from seeing the contents (but still use what lays within) all folders in the machine that are not in their own home folder. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path/to/directory/ -type d -exec chmod o-r {} \;
```

should work. For every folder, `find` executes `chmod`. `chmod` then removes the read bit for others.

Comment: I hope a new user doesn't read this and unwittingly use:  `sudo find / -type d -exec chmod o-r {} +`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix could you add a bit more about why that wolud be a problem? More specifically, why would it be bad for the root to do that and then set only the users' subfolders under `home` to be readable for users?

Comment: Most new users here are on a single user system.

Answer (score 0):

Only binary objects opened by the kernel itself can be flagged as executable but not readable. Any type of script (bash, python, etc.) would have to be first read before being executed. See:

- [Can a script be executable but not readable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34202/can-a-script-be-executable-but-not-readable)

Comment: Jorget Millani wanted all *folders* to get the read permission removed. And a file in a folder without read permission but execute permission can still be acessed if one knows the file-name of the file inside the folder.