# Create Jailed Users Using Programing Language

Tags: 12.04, server, permissions, chroot

I want to create limited users in my system able to use only few commands.

I read this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93411/simple-easy-way-to-jail-users) and `jailkit` is awesome and do what I want, except one thing creating the users dynamically (via programming language).

Is there any method to create jailed users via programming language ? or I should invoke `jailkit` commands from my program ?

**ps**: I believe every programming language should be able to do it. anyway I prefer nodejs or python.