# Jailkit freezing

Tags: ssh, users, chroot

I'm trying to jail ssh users on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. So after installing Jailkit version 2.17 (with the help of [this tutorial](http://www.binarytides.com/install-jailkit-ubuntu-debian/)) I'm now trying to follow [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93411/simple-easy-way-to-jail-users) to use Jailkit. After running the first Jailkit command however, it shows a couple lines of output and then seems to stop doing anything:

```
$ sudo jk_init -v jail basicshell
Source file(s) /lib/libnsl.so.1 do not exist
Source file(s) /lib64/libnsl.so.1 do not exist
Source file(s) /lib/libnss*.so.2 do not exist
Source file(s) /lib64/libnss*.so.2 do not exist
Source file(s) /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 do not exist
Source file(s) /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss*.so.2 do not exist
Create directory jail/lib
Create directory jail/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I first thought it simply takes a while, but was hanging for more than half an hour. I Ctrl+C it, and tried again, but with the same result.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the full path for the jail directory?

```
sudo jk_init -v -j /home/jail basicshell
```