# How to create a very limited user on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, printing, users, transfer, restricted-access

I'm trying to make a safe workstation PC for sensitive data using Ubuntu 14.04.

No user should have the right to: print, connect a USB flash drive to transfer files, send files via email or install new softwares.

I'd like the restricted user to only be able to read files and not transfer them in any way possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can create limited user by jail-users :
[simple-easy-way-to-jail-users](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93411/simple-easy-way-to-jail-users)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

Then you have an interface to add users :

[image]

Whit many options :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527876/how-to-restrict-a-linux-user-to-be-only-able-to-read-home-user-and-nothing-else

"Usually it's enough to make sure they can't mess with the home directories of other users. To do this, put the user into a new group (like "untrusted"), chown his home directory and revoke the group and other rights on all home directories: chmod go-rwx /home/*/"

Comment: The link you gave 404's

Comment: Unfortunately it does now. The article was deleted on stackoverflow because it was off-topic, despite being very useful.  When you get 10k rep on stackoverflow, you too will finally have a complete view of the web, because you can see deleted questions.