# How to jail users under Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: users, chroot

Following [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/102206/660555) gives a solution about **Simple & easy way to jail users**. Multiple comments mention that it does not work on Ubuntu 13.10, but there is no verification about that.

I have tried that solution on `Ubuntu 17.10 LTS`. I was not able to make it work.

Setup: (Please note that I have get the code [from](https://askubuntu.com/a/102206/660555) with small changes.)

```
cd /tmp
wget http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/jailkit-2.17.tar.gz
tar -zxvf jailkit-2.17.tar.gz
cd jailkit-2.17
./configure
make
make install

jailDir='/var/lib/jail'
sudo mkdir $jailDir
sudo chown root:root $jailDir

sudo jk_init -v $jailDir basicshell
sudo jk_init -v $jailDir netutils
sudo jk_init -v $jailDir ssh
sudo jk_init -v $jailDir jk_lsh

sudo useradd -d /var/lib/testuser -m testuser -s /bin/bash
sudo jk_jailuser -m -j $jailDir testuser
sudo jk_cp -v -f $jailDir /bin/bash
```

---

Later when I try to jail the user, I have faced following issues:

**=>** When I did `sudo su - testuser`, I can see other jailed users' files, but I do not have access to `/home`. It seems promising but now I cannot see any of the installed binaries and use them.

**=>** `sudo -su testuser` opens at the current directory I am, and it can still see other users' directory and files under `/home`.

Please note that I am not doing ssh into the user, I am just switching the users after I have logged in.

**[Q]** Is it possible to do jail users under Ubuntu 17.10? It it correct way to do this?

Comment: Sorry `17.10` will be enough. FYI I observe same case on both versions. @user535733