# How to create user without a password in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, sudo, useradd

I am using `Ubuntu 19.10`.I want add a system user with a home directory, and the user won't have any login access or password. I want to accomplish this by running `useradd` without `sudo` command.

I gave following permission to the main user using `sudo visudo`:

```
main_user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: \
    /usr/sbin/useradd, /usr/bin/chmod, /usr/sbin/userdel, /usr/bin/setfacl, /usr/sbin/usermod
```

---

I have followed answer [Creating a user without a password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56847/198423) but seems like there is no `--disabled-password` parameter in `useradd`. Even there was, would it prevent `useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.` error, since I believe it won't access into the `passwd` file.

```
useradd -d /var/users/general -m general --shell /bin/bash
```

error:

```
useradd: Permission denied.
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

Comment: `NOPASSWD` does not mean "no sudo" - you'd still need to prefix the `useradd` command with `sudo`

Comment: I believe this also stands for `userdel` since I am getting the same error for it as well

Comment: `sudo` is needed because only an admin can create/delete user accounts. It is unrelated to the permissions of the user that is being created/deleted/modified. That's a different setting.

Comment: Like a guest User? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120448/disable-persistence-on-hdd-install-public-pc/1120537#1120537

Comment: @C.S.Cameron yes and no. I am actually trying to accomplish kind of a `jail` with dummy users I created (https://askubuntu.com/q/1034993/660555). There is only a single user able to login in to system, and running jobs under dummy users forcing, those jobs not to overwrite other users's folders with additional permission (https://superuser.com/a/1342600/723632).
Ex: only a user A have access to `/home/A/` and the main user able to run a slurm-script as user- `A`, which only allows that code to run under `/home/A`.