# Disallow command usage for a specific user

Tags: command-line, server, users, user-management, restricted-access

I recently bought a VPS with Ubuntu 18.04 (Server) on it, and ever since I've started using it I've been spammed by one of my friends regarding that he wants an account. I wanna take some revenge on the spamming by pulling a prank on him by creating an account that has no access to any binary file/command, the goal is to make his account only be able to write in the command line but really have no access to execute any commands. His account won't be added to the sudoers list.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Richard.

Comment: Possibly related: [Simple & easy way to jail users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93411/simple-easy-way-to-jail-users)

Comment: Using `bash -r` with an empty PATH might work.

Comment: Cheers for that link, was really helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You might make his login shell a script that has an empty PATH variable. Don't know if it will work, but it might get you started.

Comment: how to do so ??

Comment: It was a very nice idea, however the user can still export their own environment variables using `export`.https://ibb.co/i8b9to

Comment: Even if you prevent him from setting his own PATH, he would still be able to call programs using their full path (e.g. `/bin/ls`).

Comment: So @wjandrea, is there a way to restrict the permissions from that user (as root) to access the binary files?